# Redo lag on AG readable secondaries: is there a way to overcome it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I have a quite busy (1000+ batch requests per second, 350+ workers on average) system built on sql server 2016. It's an availability group with 3 synchronous replicas.
I'd like to redirect read requests on secondaries, but due to the redo lag (and the way the app works), I'm concerned about the fetched data being stale.

I know I can get the last hardened lsn and last redone lsn from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states - but is there any way to wait for the redo to catch up avoiding a while loop?

Thanks!
Gabriele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a few different questions in here:

**Could a query be modified to check to see if redo is current on the underlying data is done, and if not, stall execution until redo catches up?** This seems like a really dangerous idea because when replication gets behind, you'll have more and more queries using up worker threads, waiting for replication to catch up. I can easily see worker thread exhaustion hitting here and causing threadpool waits because it's essentially the same scenario that blocking causes.

**Could queries be redirected to the most current secondary?** Yes, by using a load balancer between your app and the SQL Servers. You can build logic into load balancers to run periodic health checks, and when a server fails the load check, it's taken out of the available connection list until it's able to pass health checks again. This is a pretty common strategy for web servers, but fairly rare for database servers (since it's a lot of work to build out.)

**Can redo be done faster?** Yes, test to see whether serial or parallel redo is a better fit for your workloads, and make sure you're getting the one you want. [Microsoft has blogged about the gotchas with parallel redo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-20162017-availability-group-secondary-replica-redo-model-and-performance/), including gems like only the first databases in your AG (by database ID) get parallel redo.